# Inserting elements at specific index after regex match in a array in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a code block which is creating an array where I am searching for certain text using regex and if its found, I am removing that element and inserting two new elements in its place with below code:

```
var Unique_items = ["P name1-Test based fee-200 Samples", "P name2-night fee-GG", "P name2-day light test-HH" ];
for (var i in Unique_items){
    var temp_index = [];
    var check_test_based_fee = new RegExp(/Test based fee/).test(Unique_items[i]); 

    if (check_test_based_fee==true){
      temp_index.push(i);
      temp_index.push(i+1);
      
      Unique_items.splice(temp_index[0],"P name1-TBF-200 Samples:commitment");
      Unique_items.splice(temp_index[1],"P name1-TBF-200 Samples:Excess");
    }
  }
Logger.log(Unique_items);
```

So, whenever `Test based fee` is encountered in any element, it should replace it in the array with two new elements as the `Unique_items` here to be

```
["P name1-TBF-200 Samples:commitment", "P name1-TBF-200 Samples:Excess","P name2-night fee-GG", "P name2-day light test-HH"]
```

I am not getting how to dynamically prepare and insert the

```
P name1-TBF-200 Samples:commitment", P name1-TBF-200 Samples:Excess
```

Please help!

Comment: Please share an example of the desired output. Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: @Lorena Gomez, the above question did have a reproducible example if you look closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the following conversion using `var Unique_items = ["P name1-Test based fee-200 Samples", "P name2-night fee-GG", "P name2-day light test-HH"];` and `"P name1-TBF-200 Samples:commitment"` and `"P name1-TBF-200 Samples:Excess"`.

  ```
    ["P name1-TBF-200 Samples:commitment", "P name1-TBF-200 Samples:Excess","P name2-night fee-GG", "P name2-day light test-HH"]
  ```

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `splice` is required to be modified. the arguments of `splice` is `splice(start, deleteCount, item1, item2, itemN)`.
- If 2 elements are included in `Unique_items`, the index of `i` is changed. It is required to consider this situation.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
var Unique_items = ["P name1-Test based fee-200 Samples", "P name2-night fee-GG", "P name2-day light test-HH"];
for (var i in Unique_items) {
  var check_test_based_fee = Unique_items[i].includes("Test based fee");
  if (check_test_based_fee == true) {
    Unique_items.splice(i, 1, ["P name1-TBF-200 Samples:commitment", "P name1-TBF-200 Samples:Excess"]);
  }
}
Unique_items = Unique_items.flat();
console.log(Unique_items);
```

#### Note:

- In this case, the following sample script might be able to be used.

```js
var Unique_items = ["P name1-Test based fee-200 Samples", "P name2-night fee-GG", "P name2-day light test-HH"];
var res = Unique_items.reduceRight((ar, e) => [...ar, ...(e.includes("Test based fee") ? ["P name1-TBF-200 Samples:Excess", "P name1-TBF-200 Samples:commitment"] : [e])], []).reverse();
console.log(res)
```

#### Reference:

- [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: You are a blessing for humankind, Thank you so much @Tanaike - san!

Comment: @Alicia Stone Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.